# Nuxt 3 route redirect on page and public directory with the same name

Tags: redirect, nuxtjs3

I have a `foo.vue` page and a `foo` directory under public.

```
pages
  foo.vue
public
  foo
```

When I load the page locally with "/localhost:3000/foo", the page is loaded, but the browser adds a trailing slash at the end, and there is a 301 redirect from the original URL to the one with the slash.

When it's deployed to Vercel, the page can also be loaded with the same URL, but I don't see 301 redirect and no trailing slash is added.

Either with or without trailing slash, I want dev and prod behave consistently.

In my `nuxt.config.ts`, the only suspicious line is,

```
ssr: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
```

I added this line to make some Vuetify components happy.

I read this [Nuxt issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15462) a few times, didn't figure out a fix.

So, how do I get consistent trailing slash or no slash on dev and prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `pages/foo.vue` to `pages/foo/index.vue`